# Extracting and flattening data from an Oracle Apex SQL table with multiple lookup tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, etl, servicenow

I am working in ServiceNow with an external Oracle Apex database, and the goal is to gather data from a main table, that has 21 references to different lookup tables. Each of these lookup tables maintains its own "modified datetime" column.

ServiceNow, when loading data from a JDBC data source, expects a datetime column on the source table which it will use to perform delta queries and reduce the amount of data that needs to be loaded on a schedule. This has to be a single column, it does not handle columns. This would be fine if I only needed to use the data from the main table, but if data in a lookup table has changed, it won't impact the main table's modified datetime returned for that record.

I want to look up every record on the main table, then look up each reference on the lookup tables, and compare each lookup table's last modified datetime, and pick the newest one out of all of them to return as the true last modified datetime for that record, then do that for each record selected on the main table.

I tried this, but it seems to have just taken the newest date from all of the referenced tables, regardless of which record on the main table I started with

```
SELECT
    main_view.*,
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT MAX(update_datetime) FROM table1),
        (SELECT MAX(update_datetime) FROM table2),
        -- Add more subqueries for the remaining lookup tables...
        (SELECT MAX(update_datetime) FROM table21)
    ) AS most_recent_update_datetime
FROM
    your_existing_view main_view;
```

So rather than each returned record having a different datetime, they all returned 06-APR-2023

I can extract the query from the view I am using and modify it, but this is above any SQL work I've done in the past.

This is guidance based on a response from ChatGPT

I believe I could solve this by disabling "Use last run datetime" in the ServiceNow data source, but this violates best practices for JDBC data sources (causes each scheduled load to do a full database query, rather than a delta)

Answer (score 0):

> I am working in ServiceNow with an external Oracle Apex database

- That's most probably wrongly said. There's no "Oracle Apex" database; did you mean "XE" (Express Edition)? Apex ("Application Express") is a **tool** used to develop web applications based on an Oracle database.

---

> and the goal is to gather data from a main table, that has 21 references to different lookup tables. Each of these lookup tables maintains its own "modified datetime" column.

- OK, so the final result is `select * From main_table where ...`, i.e. you don't need to fetch data from any of 21 lookup tables, but you do have to compare main table's `modified_datetime` to each of 21 lookup tables' `modified_datetime` values.

---

Query you posted uses the `coalesce` function. The way I see it, that's a wrong choice. It accepts two (or more) parameters and returns the first one which is not null. For example:

```
SQL> select coalesce (null, null, 'A', null, 'B') result from dual;

R
-
A
```

Presuming that there's at least one row in each of 21 lookup tables, your code returns MAX `updated_datetime` from `table1`; the rest is *ignored*. Did you mean to use `greatest` function? It returns MAX value of all parameters involved?

```
SQL> select greatest
  2    (date '2023-01-15',    -- 15th of January 2023
  3     date '2023-05-18',    -- 18th of May
  4     date '2023-08-15'     -- 15th of August (today) -> that's the greatest value here
  5    ) as result
  6  from dual;

RESULT
-----------
15-Aug-2023

SQL>
```

---

Here's how I understood it.

Sample data (main table and 3 lookup tables):

```
SQL> select * from main_table;

        ID MODIFIED_DATETIME
---------- --------------------
         1 13-Aug-2023
         2 14-Aug-2023
         3 17-Aug-2023          --> this row's modified datetime isn't largest
                                    than MAX update datetime from lookup tables,
                                    so its data shouldn't be gathered

SQL> select * from table1;

UPDATE_DATETIME
--------------------
26-Jul-2023

SQL> select * from table2;

UPDATE_DATETIME
--------------------
05-Aug-2023

SQL> select * from table3;

UPDATE_DATETIME
--------------------
15-Aug-2023            --> this is MAX update datetime in all lookup tables
```

Query would then look like this:

```
SQL> with t_greatest as
  2    (select greatest ( (select max(update_datetime) from table1),
  3                       (select max(update_datetime) from table2),
  4                       (select max(update_datetime) from table3)
  5                     ) max_lookup_datetime
  6     from dual
  7    )
  8  select m.id, m.modified_datetime,
  9    case when m.modified_datetime < g.max_lookup_datetime then 'gather data'
 10         else 'do not gather data'
 11    end as what_to_do
 12  from t_greatest g cross join main_table m;

        ID MODIFIED_DATETIME    WHAT_TO_DO
---------- -------------------- ------------------
         1 13-Aug-2023          gather data
         2 14-Aug-2023          gather data
         3 17-Aug-2023          do not gather data

SQL>
```

---

Or, instead of the `greatest` function, you could `union` all MAX `update_datetime` values and fetch MAX of them; result is the same, see which behaves better.

```
SQL> with t_greatest as
  2    (select max(update_datetime) max_lookup_datetime
  3     from
  4       (select max(update_datetime) update_datetime from table1 union all
  5        select max(update_datetime)                 from table2 union all
  6        select max(update_datetime)                 from table3
  7       )
  8    )
  9  select m.id, m.modified_datetime,
 10    case when m.modified_datetime < g.max_lookup_datetime then 'gather data'
 11         else 'do not gather data'
 12    end as what_to_do
 13  from t_greatest g cross join main_table m;

        ID MODIFIED_DATETIME    WHAT_TO_DO
---------- -------------------- ------------------
         1 13-Aug-2023          gather data
         2 14-Aug-2023          gather data
         3 17-Aug-2023          do not gather data

SQL>
```

There might (and probably are) other options as well, but I hope that this might get you started.